# name reference in countif criteria_range and criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, countif

Sheet1 contains ip address in column 'A'.

Sample:

```
    A
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.2
```

i have name references for columns as: 'ip'. for ips i have given name reference as 'ip1_' for 1.1.1.2 and 'ip2_' for 1.1.1.3

I want to count how many times "1.1.1.3" and "1.1.1.2" are falling in column A.

i have used countif formula as:

```
=countif(ip,ip1_,ip,ip2_)
```

but the result is '0'. if i use only one criteria then it gives exact count, but on multiple criteria with name references for 'Criteria_range' and 'Criteria' it doesn't work.

i am having ip addresses in sheet 1 and so it becomes tiring writing long cell references as

```
=countif(sheet1!A:A,"1.1.1.2",sheet1!A:A,"1.1.1.3")
```

and also writing complete Ip addres in criteria invites mistakes.

Comment: If you want to count more than one criterion you should use `COUNTIFS` (with and s at the end). However, such a formula would look for both criteria to be true which would never be the case. To count both, use an addition, like `COUNTIF(ip,ip1_) + COUNIF(ip, ip2_)`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the COUNTIF in a SUM and make your OR conditions a string constant array.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A, {"1.1.1.2","1.1.1.3"}))
```

This is **not** an array (i.e. CSE) formula. Note that I changed one of your values to 1.1.1.4 for demonstration purposes.

Depending on how many subnets are in your IP range, the following wildcard syntax may be better for you.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A, {"*.2","*.3"}))
```

This method of applying OR conditions to a COUNTIF **cannot** be used with named ranges in the string constant array. However, with 1.1.1.2 and 1.1.1.3 in a two-cell named range (e.g. ips_) then it works as an array formula with CSE -

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(ip, ips_))
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on how many subnets are in your IP range, `=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A, {"*.2","*.3"}))` may be better for you.

Comment: Nice. For sake of completeness It would be useful to state if this form can handle the named constants `ip1_` and `ip2_`...

Comment: That's a good point @A.S.H; particularly so as it cannot. I'll make the edit.

Comment: However, with 1.1.1.2 and 1.1.1.3 in a two-cell named range (e.g. ips_) then it works as an array formula with CSE - `=SUM(COUNTIF(ip, ips_))`

Comment: @Jeeped SUMPRODUCT without CSE is also sufficient. And with the Named Constants in non-contiguous cells we can use CHOOSE.

Comment: You really should make that an answer @XORLX.

Comment: @Jeeped What? With CHOOSE for non-contiguous Named Ranges? Has the OP confirmed somewhere that this is the case?

Comment: I think the bottom line is that you cannot use named constants inside `{constant arrays}`. Nor can you use named ranges and native addresses, such as `{A2, A3}`. That's unfortunate somehow :(

Comment: @XORLX - The OP believes that named ranges will expedite the task (although I am not convinced of that) and uses multiple  single cell named ranges which he/she wants to use in OR condition for COUNTIF. Since that cannot be done, alternatives are the only thing to be  offered.

Comment: @A.S.H - Yes, but multiple single cell named ranges aren't really a good idea anyways. If there are a lot of IPs (that change often) then a dynamic named range is the best solution.

Comment: @Jeeped I agree with you, it's better design wise.

Comment: @jeeped,
in the above formula can i replace {"1.1.1.2","1.1.1.3"} with ip1_ and ip2_ and A:A with ip (name ranges) ?

that is the formula i want to use (like)
=sum(countif(ip, {ip1_,ip2_})

Comment: You can replace A:A with ip but you **cannot** replace {"1.1.1.2","1.1.1.3"} with ip1_ and ip2_. Please read the comments and review the alternatives I've added to my response above.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Named Ranges within non-contiguous ranges:

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(ip,CHOOSE({1,2},ip1_,ip2_)))`

Regards